# Navigating to a different html page using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am writing PHP code to validate the existence of username and password in a mysql database. This php is called when I click on the signin button on the login page (index.html). My php code is below:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

// Unescape the string values in the JSON array
$logindata = stripcslashes($_POST['pLogData']);

// Decode the JSON array
$logindata = json_decode($logindata,TRUE);

// now $tableData can be accessed like a PHP array
$user_email = $logindata['user'];
$user_password = $logindata['pass'];

//First lets get the username and password from the user
$query = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE email=:user_email LIMIT 1");

$query->execute(array(':user_email'=>$user_email));

$userRow=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['pass'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['userid'];
        if($userRow['userid'] == 1) {
            header("Location: adminPanel.html");
        } else {
            header("Location: main_dashboard.html");
        }
        // return true;
    } else {
        header("Location: index.html");
        // return false;
    }
}
?>
```

The ajax call code is:

```
function login(username, passwd) {
   var loginData = {
       'user': username,
       'pass': passwd
    };

   loginData = $.toJSON(loginData);

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "loginValidate.php",
       data: "pLogData=" + loginData,
       success: function(msg) {
           console.log(msg);
           // return value stored in msg variable
       }
   });
}
```

It is working fine except that the navigation set in php is not happening. I am unable to figure out where the mistake is. The entire html that it has to navigate to is getting printed into the console.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: through ajax it won't work. return the `file name` and use `window.location=filename` in javascript. or submit the form and if uncussessfull redirect to current else on `main_dashboard.html`.

Comment: @Suchit, what you have suggested works but I need to hit a server for validating the username and password. Which is easy using php. If I replace the html with php file, it is able to switch.  I want to know why it is not switching for html file.

Comment: .html does not recognizes the php code.if you want to use ajax then after validation return the file name and use it to redirect.

Comment: OK. Will try that

Comment: You could load the whole `main_dashboard.html` with ajax and then write your `html` content into the body of your `index` page using `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through ajax it won't work. return the file name and use `window.location=filename` in javascript. or submit the form and if 
uncussessfull redirect to current else on `main_dashboard.html(the desired page)`.

If you return the file name you can do this:

```
 success: function(filename) {
       window.location=filename;
   }
```

for this remove header location and use `echo filename` like main_dashboard.html or other.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your valuable suggestions. I managed to solve the issue. The working code is as below:

```
if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    $upass = $userRow['pass'];
    // if(password_verify($user_password, $userRow['pass'])) {
    if($user_password == $upass) {
        //echo "Check verified";
        $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['userid'];

        if($userRow['userid'] == 1) {
            //header("Location: http://localhost:90/codebase-test/adminPanel.html");
            //return $userRow['userid'];
            $filename = "adminPanel.html";
            //return $filename;
        }
        else{
            $filename = "main_dashboard.html";
            //return $filename;
        }
        echo $filename;
       // return true;
    }
    else {
        echo "index.html";
        //echo $filename;
        //return false;
    }
}
```

I have posted only the bit that I changed. It is working now.

**EDIT**
I also made a small change to the ajax call. Code below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loginValidate.php",
    data: "pLogData=" + loginData,
    success: function(filename){
        window.location = filename;
    }
});
```